# PDO returns wrong rowCount() after SELECT statement

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Im executing code similar to this:

```
// first select
$query = $link->prepare("
            SELECT id FROM table
            WHERE name = ?;"); 

$param = 'foo';

$query->bindParam(1, $param); // should return 1 row
$query->execute();
echo $query->rowCount(); // displays 0 (??????)
```

Other example:

```
// second select
$query = $link->prepare("
            SELECT id FROM table
            WHERE name = ?;"); // should return 0 rows

$param = 'bar';

$query->bindParam(1, $param);
$query->execute();
echo $query->rowCount(); // displays 1 (?????)
```

My table:

```
id | name
---------
1  | foo
```

I don't understand.

Comment: Just a wild stab - I don't think you need the semi-colons at the end of the sql statements.

Comment: btw, you don't need to prepare between 2 executes. Only bind. That's the idea.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I don't execute them one afeter one, just showed 2 examples in one block of code.

Comment: @Raad I put semicolon on the end of line almost everywhere. Habitually :)

Comment: Some databases may return the number of rows returned by a SELECT statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on .[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: @davidstrachan It may be enough for me. You may add it as answer, i will accept.

Comment: @Kamil I have provided answer and added some additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some databases may return the number of rows returned by a SELECT statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on .[**Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) You can use `COUNT(*)` and `fetchColumn()` as in following query to emulate `rowCount()`.

```
$query = $link->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table  WHERE name = ?");
$param = 'bar';
$query->bindParam(1,$param);
$query->execute();
// Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement 
if($query->fetchColumn() == 0) {
    echo "No records found";
 }else{
        $query = $link->prepare("SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = ?")
        //Etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `bindParam` method is the wrong one, it expects a variable or name of a variable.  You want to use `bindValue` instead, which expects a literal value as you have used.

Manual references:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: In my application I was binding variable there. I tried to simplify the code example and I put strings there. Anyway, I didn't knew that I shouldnt/cant call bindParam with value. Thanks.