# Interactive email check - Am I missing something here?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My assignment requires some Ajax/JQuery to interactively check if a username is available. This is what I have, but it does not work. I do not have a lot of experience obviously.

**PHP Back-end**

```
    <?php

  if($_POST) 
  {
      $email     = strip_tags($_POST['email']);

   $stmt=$dbcon->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=:email");
   $stmt->execute(array(':email'=>$email));
   $count=$stmt->rowCount();

   if($count>0)
   {
    echo "<span style='color:brown;'>Sorry username already taken !!!</span>";
   }
   else
   {
    echo "<span style='color:green;'>available</span>";
   }
  }
?>
```

I have taken out the DB connection for obvious reasons.

**JS Script I am using**

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{    
 $("#email").keyup(function()
 {  
  var email = $(this).val(); 

  if(email.length > 3)
  {  
   $("#user-result").html('checking...');

   /*$.post("username-check.php", $("#reg-form").serialize())
    .done(function(data){
    $("#result").html(data);
   });*/

   $.ajax({

    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'checkemail.php',
    data : $(this).serialize(),
    success : function(data)
        {
              $("#user-result").html(data);
           }
    });
    return false;

  }
  else
  {
   $("#user-result").html('');
  }
 });

});
```

There is a span with the ID mentioned which is supposed to display the text, but nothing actually happens. Been stuck here for a while.

Comment: F12 browser tools and look for script errors, then look at the Network tab and inspect what is being sent/received to/from the script.

Comment: `PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object. ` https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: Maybe, it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15010497/3943162

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `count(*)` instead :

```
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE email=:email"); 
$stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email));
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Hope this can help you.